# How to: Automator, launch an app, as if I dragged n dropped file on App's dock icon?

Tags: macos, applescript, automator, dock, ui

Using automator, I know how to "Launch an App". 
I would like to know how to "Launch an App in a specific way".

The app I want to launch, acts differently depending how its launched. If one:

1. clicks the dock icon.. then gives you a menu to select file etc..
2. drop the file onto the dock item.. then automatically performs an action

Using automator, I want to Launch this App, option 2)
Any ideas?

thankyou

Comment: You want to use an if/else statement for this. Automator itself has no such capability, but you can use Applescript or Shell scripting for this.

Comment: Thankyou @CousinCocaine.  
I could find how to in Shell yet. For applescript I found the basic open command  (which is also available in automator). e.g. "To launch an app (using a command), you'd have to do something like the following:

'open /Applications/Transmission.app'.   However, what is syntax to make the .app launch as the .app currently launches from the dock?

Comment: OPTION: Create a **Droplet** using AppleScript. (http://www.macosxautomation.com/applescript/sbrt/sbrt-10.html)
**Droplets** are specialized AppleScript applets which are designed to process items dragged onto them. Their icon contains a downward pointing arrow indicating their status as a droplet.

Droplets are written in a specific manner using the on open handler. The following examples can be used as templates for easily creating your own droplets. Complete set of pre-formed script droplet templates (http://www.macosxautomation.com/applescript/pkg/droplet-templates.zip)

Comment: this should be an answer.

Comment: For me, It is an **option** only at this stage requiring investigation and testing.  Droplet is better in code of the original App. So next is to work out for Apps I purchased can I see the objects they are calling to write such a script or must the App be open source.